# Dates in Table are submitted in incorrect regional format

Tags: date, excel, excel-2010, vba

**Background Info**
I currently have a VBA user form, which submits daily KPIs to an Excel Table in Excel 2010. The Form is setup to put today's date into a text box in the format DD/MM/YYYY (I'm in Australia), then transfer that information to the Excel worksheet when I hit submit. Previously, this process has worked without a hitch, as it is just transferring pure text. But now, the date is being submitted in US format (MM/DD/YYYY). I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere in Excel, but here is my VBA code anyway:

```
  'First it populates the text box    
    Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
         TextBox1.Text = Format(Now(), "DD/MM/YYYY")
         End Sub
    'Then it transfers to the spreadsheet
     With nwb.Sheets("daily_tracking_dataset_master")
        .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
```

**Main Problem**
Somewhere on the Excel side, the data is now being submitted incorrectly in the US date format, so a submission on the fourth of June, becomes the sixth of April, see image: http://tinypic.com/r/2vslyd5/8/.

When i change the number format to General, it shows that the pure text date from the VBA form has been converted to the April date. I.e. it's not a simple matter of changing the formatting, the date has actually been completely changed:

- 41789 (30/05/2014)
- 41789 (30/05/2014)
- 41789 (30/05/2014)
- 41735 (06/04/2014)
- 41735 (06/04/2014)
- 41735 (06/04/2014)

I have tried several workarounds for this, including:

1. Highlighting column A and changing the format to Date in the format DD/MM/YY
2. Selecting Date format under the Home tab -> Number group -> Date drop down box
3. Checking regional settings in Windows and Excel
4. I have also tried going into Data -> Data Tools -> Text to columns. Then on step 3 selecting DMY under Date - this seems to be one of the main fixes for the issue I'm having in other forums.

By the nature of the Excel Table, each time my submission form adds a record, the table is extended by one row - I'm not sure whether this would have any influence and the incorrect date settings are generated from the Table somehow?

Any ideas for troubleshooting this would be fantastic.

Comment: Did you try `.Cells(emptyRow, 1) = Format(TextBox1.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that comes up with the same issue. The VBA side was working fine before :)

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue. When I add a new date to a table where the date column is formatted as "General," using this syntax: `Range("A2") = Format(Now(), "DD/MM/YYYY")`, I get the expected output of _4/6/2014_.

Comment: If it was working fine before, have you reverted any changes to your code you've made since then? Perhaps setting a breakpoint on `.Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value` and checking the value of `TextBox1` before writing to the sheet would be helpful.

Comment: Hi ARich,
I've tried a few things now. 
1. I've directed the submission form to submit to a brand new workbook with no formatting - the same error exists.
2. I've followed your second option by disregarding the textbox altogether and using .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Format(Now(), "DD/MM/YYYY")
3. I've also stepped through the data and the textbox value is 04/06/2014.
Since I made no changes to the VBA code when the error occurred (I was working purely in Excel with pivot tables), I'm guessing its an Excel issue. But since I've submitted to a brand new book with no formatting, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Use `cdate(textbox1.text)`

Comment: Sorry Rory,
I'm not exactly sure where I would be using the cdate expression. Do I use it to populate the text box and then copy the values later? If so, how would I construct this to test it out? I currently have TextBox1.Text = Format(Now(), "DD/MM/YYYY"). Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: When writing back to the cell: `.Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = cdate(TextBox1.Value)`

Comment: I know. ;) Glad to help.

Comment: @Rory, did you want to convert this to an answer rather than a comment and I'll vote it up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CDate when writing back to the cell to convert the text to a real date value so that VBA can't misinterpret it:

```
.Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = cdate(TextBox1.Value)
```